# Get content type columns/metadata for an item

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

How to get content type columns or metadata for an item in SharePoint document library?

This links gives the file properties that i don't need
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.properties.aspx

I only to want to get content type columns for an item.
I tried this string strXML = oItem.Xml.ToString();  but it gives me same garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ContentType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.contenttype%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property of an `SPListItem`. If you want all content types in a list, you can use the [`ContentTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.contenttypes%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property of an `SPList`. Once you have a content type reference, you can check its [`Fields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.fields%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property to get the columns.

Content Types for a list item:

```
SPContentType contentType = myListItem.ContentType;

foreach (SPField field in contentType)
{
    // Do your stuff with this column
}
```

Content Types for a list:

```
SPContentTypeCollection contentTypes = myList.ContentTypes;
List<object> values = new List<object>();
List<SPContentTypeId> blackList = new List<SPContentTypeId>()
{
    SPBuiltInContentTypeId.System,
    SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Item,
};

var goodContentTypes = contentTypes.Where(c => !blackList.Contains(c.Id));

foreach (SPContentType contentType in goodContentTypes)
{
    foreach (SPField field in contentType.Fields)
    {
        // Do your stuff with this column e.g. Get value from item
        values.Add(myListItem[field.InternalName]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this method also brings sharepoint's system columns (created, select, modified, etc.) which I dont want and that is why i only wanted extract the column name and it's value by content type.

Comment: You can filter out whatever content types you don't want based on the content type's name or id. See [partial list of system content type ids](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452896.aspx). To get the values, you can match up the `SPField`s you got from the content type with your actual list item.

Answer (score 0):

Get the list that represents your document library.  Once you have this you can look at the columns.  I typically use this method:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;  
SPList list = web.Lists["Your list name"];  
foreach (String field in list.DefaultView.ViewFields)  
{  
   //whatever
}
```

Which I believe gives you all the columns for the default view.  You can also use this method:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;  
SPList list = web.Lists["Your list name"];  
foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)  
{  
   //whatever
}
```

Which will give you info for all fields in the list (library) regardless of the view.

Comment: my lists default view only contains 6 fields. The content type has about 15 fields.

Comment: Abe, your method gives me content type columns. so far so good. But it only gives me the column name and I need the value as well.